wordrpress install with postgres database error
On my Ubuntu machine I have installed wordpress and plugin for postgresql (PG4WP):
https://github.com/PostgreSQL-For-Wordpress/postgresql-for-wordpress
here it is wp-config.php file:
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'postgres' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'pass' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

define('AUTH_KEY',         'Where');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'Where');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'Where');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'Where');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'Where');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'Where');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'Where');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'Where');

$table_prefix = 'wp_';

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';


I get error when starting install (on welcome screen):
WordPress database error: []
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp\_users'


I tried creating saparate PG database since I initially tried to use existing one, but error remains.
I have also changed port for  wordpress installation from default 80 to 86, but don't now how that can be related to this problem.
Log from Postgresql:
2024-06-09 13:03:30.444 UTC [337602] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-06-09 13:03:30 UTC
2024-06-09 13:03:30.451 UTC [337593] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-06-09 13:04:01.576 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.576 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'
2024-06-09 13:04:01.576 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.576 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'
2024-06-09 13:04:01.608 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.608 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.608 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.608 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'home' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'home' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress STATEMENT:  SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
2024-06-09 13:04:01.609 UTC [337670] postgres@wpress ERROR:  relation "wp_options" does not exist at character 26


Try to set up the port:  define('DB_PORT', '5432');

@Alex Tried that, no luck.  Tried with 'localhost:5432' , same error.

SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp\_users' is not valid SQL for PostgreSQL. It looks like you're connected to a database where no tables have been created, or the tables have a different name. Use psql, or any other client, to connect to your database and check what tables have been created.

@FrankHeikens Tables are being created, but they are empty for some reason. However, I found that when accessing from web apache2 username is "www-data", so I created that user and give it rights. I did that, but now, entire connection is not available. Probably Ill have to setup permissions now for that www-data user to connect to db.
